# How to check what triggered high CPU usage on past days, on Digital Ocean?

Tags: cpu-usage, high-load, digital-ocean

I want to investigate what caused a high cpu usage for several hours on 1/16. Digital Ocean graph shows a prolonged high cpu usage in the course of about 12 hours. Is there a log somewhere that I can tap into that would reveal to me more detail about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital Ocean doesn't logs your processes. This will mess up with your VM and privacy.

You have to log these on your own inside your VM. One of the options is to use `atop` tool, it can start as a daemon and log usage stats into a file. There a lot of other options actually.

Digital Ocean even have an article on this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-monitor-cpu-use-on-digitalocean-droplets

But it actually offers to enable alerts on total CPU usage with their tools and later use a `top` tool for real-time analysis. I think `atop` record usage to a file approach are more feasible.

Comment: Thank you, will do.